# Importing data in R from Excel with information cotained in header

Tags: r, excel, import

As title says, I am trying to import data from Excel to R, where part of the information is contained in the header.

I a very simplified way, the Excel I have looks like this:

```
GROUP;1234
MONTH;"Jan"
PERSON;SEX;AGE;INCOME
John;m;26;20000
Michael;m;24;40000
Phillip;m;25;15000
Laura;f;27;72000
Total;;;147000
```

After reading in to R, it should be a "clean" dataset that looks like this.

```
GROUP;MONTH;PERSON;SEX;AGE;INCOME
1234;Jan;John;m;26;20000
1234;Jan;Michael;m;24;40000
1234;Jan;Phillip;m;25;15000
1234;Jan;Laura;f;27;72000
```

I have several files that look like this. The number of persons however varies in each file. The last line contains a summary that should be skipped. There might be empty lines between the list and summary line.

Any help is higly apreciated.Thank you very much.

Comment: Options to read into R from Excel files often allow skipping rows, or reading a maximum number of rows. So read each file twice, first with a maximum of 2 rows, then skipping first 2 rows. Then reformatting into desired output is an easier data wrangling task

Answer (score 0):

Excel files can be read using `readxl::read_excel()`
One of the parameters is `skip`, using which you can skip certain number of rows defined by you.

For your data, you need to skip the first two lines that contain GROUP and MONTH.

You will get the data in following format.

```
PERSON;SEX;AGE;INCOME;

John;m;26;20000

Michael;m;24;40000

Phillip;m;25;15000

Laura;f;27;72000
```

After this, you can manually add the columns GROUP and MONTH

Answer (score 0):

Thank you very much for your help. The hint from @Aurèle brought the missing puzzle piece. The solution I have now come up with is as follows:

```
group <- read_excel("TEST1.xlsx", col_names = c("C1","GROUP") ,n_max = 1)
group <- group[,2]

month <- read_excel("TEST1.xlsx", col_names = c("C1","MONTH") ,skip = 1, n_max = 1)
month <- month[,2]

data <- read_excel("TEST1.xlsx", col_names = c("NAME","SEX","AGE","INCOME") , skip = 4)
data <- data[data$AGE != NA,]

data <- cbind(data,group,month)
data
```